# Do freplaced programs in XDP Dispatcher share the same instruction limit?

Tags: bpf, xdp-bpf

I am currently working with *libxdp* to multiplex execution of BPF programs for XDP.

From my understanding *libxdp* will load a *dispatcher* program and use *freplace* to change the bytecode associated with dummy functions.

After *freplace* is done, does the replacing program count towards the instruction limit of the dispatcher program?

Example, say the dispatcher is 500 instructions, and I have 4 programs consisting of 300 000 instructions each. Will I be able to freplace all 4 programs on the *dispatcher* considering their combined instruction count is 1 200 500 instructions (4 * 300 000 + 500) whereas the instruction limit of a BPF programs is 1 000 000 instructions?

Answer (score 1):

No, the dispatcher and the called program are loaded independently. The instruction/complexity limit is enforced per program at load time and is not something that is dynamically accounted for.

Also small correction on freplace. Its call this f-replace since it replaces a global function. Since any eBPF program is essentially a function, taking a context and returning a return value, we can also use other programs as such. Not to be confused with BPF-to-BPF function calls which is a slightly different mechanism. So both programs are loaded separately, then we replace the function pointer in the dispatcher with the memory address of the JIT-ed sub program. So its only a pointer value that gets patched.